# Mouseout, only vertical movement upwards

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

On my personal website [ikzoekmark.nl](http://ikzoekmark.nl/) I have added on Bootstrap Modal popup that is triggerd when an user moves over `<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" onmouseout="confirmExit()">`

This triggers an modal with some text that I would like an user to read before leaving the website.
But how trigger this script only when user movement is directed upwards? (when moving to the browser navigation bar)?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function confirmExit()
  {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make use of the clientY that is in the MouseEvent (onmouseout), you know (vertically) where the mouse left the container. With `getBoundingClientRect` you get to know the container position and can derive whether or not the mouse left above or beneath

Hope it helps, small demo

```js
const triggerElement = document.querySelector('.trigger');
const alertElement = document.querySelector('.alert');

function onMouseOut(event) {
  const {target, clientY} = event;
  const triggerBox = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (triggerBox.top > clientY) {
    // replace with your code for showing the modal
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function onAlertClick(event) {
  const {target} = event;
  target.style.display = 'none';
}

triggerElement.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
alertElement.addEventListener('click', onAlertClick);
```

```css
.trigger {
  border: 1px gray dotted;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fffff0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.alert {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  On mouse out
</div>
<div class="alert">Click to close</div>
```